# ¿Cómo comprobar si un indice de arreglo existe?

Tags: java, array

Estaba trabajando con arreglos en java, y me surgió la dudad de cómo comprobar si un indice de un arreglo existe para evitar excepciones de tipo:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Una manera de comprobar si el indice que se ingresa para retornar algún elemento del arreglo es correcto fue comparar si el mismo es mayor o igual a la longitud del arreglo, de tal manera que hice el siguiente código:

```
String a[];
a = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
int indexs = a.length;
int b = 3;
if (b >= indexs) {
    System.out.println("El indice no existe");
}else{
    System.out.println(a[b]);
}
```

Este código funciona siempre y cuando se ingrese un indice dinámico, es decir puede ser leído por teclado o por alguna interfaz gráfica, pero si quisiera hacer algo como:

```
String a[] = "Hola Mundo !".split(" ");
System.out.println(a[3]);
```

Obtendría una excepción ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Esta duda me surge ya que tengo que hacer un `split()` a algunos datos de una base de datos, los cuales pueden tener el mismo numero espacios en blanco, o ser distintos, algo así:

```
Artista:
Dave Mustaine
Dokken
```

Lo que quiero obtener es cada palabra separada por un espacio, pero si no existe el indice saltara una excepción, lógicamente puedo capturar esa excepción a través de un bloque `try catch`, pero quisiera hacerlo de ser posible con un `if`.

**¿Existe alguna manera de hacer algo así?**

Comment: No entiendo la diferencia. El largo de un array (`a.length`) es un atributo dinámico, siempre puedes preguntar si el largo alcanza para acceder al indice que deseas acceder.

Comment: Me refiero a las posiciones de un elemento del arreglo, es decir el índice; necesito acceder a los elementos que genera un split(), pero habrá casos donde no existan espacios en blanco para devolver mas de un elemento del arreglo generado con split, y el acceso a esos elementos se hace con indices estáticos, por lo que lanzará una excepción.

Comment: Sigo sin entender qué diferencia hace que el indice sea estático. Así como puedes preguntar `if( i < a.length )`  tambén puedes preguntar `if( 3 < a.length )`. Supongo que me estoy perdiendo algo.

Comment: @JuanPinzón como indica leonbloy, no se entiende la pregunta. Siempre se puede consultar la longitud de un `array` a fin de no consultar un índice mayor a su longitud y obtener una excepción. ¿Hay otro caso que crees te dará dicha excepción? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo?

Comment: En el caso de **String a[] = "Hola Mundo !".split(" "); System.out.println(a[3]);** Te dará error porque el array es de 3 elementos, contando desde 0 a 2.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear una función que valide el array y leer la posición a través de esa función...
Algo así:

```
  String g(String[] a, int pos){
      /// aquí validas la posición tal cual como indicaste
    }
```

Luego puedes emplearlo así:

```
System.out.println(g(a,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Si yo intento esto, va a tirar el error.

```
String a[] = "Hola Mundo !".split(" ");
System.out.println(a[3]);
```

Voy a copiar el código que pusiste, con la diferencia que cambio la cadena.

Antes probabas con este **array** de cadenas.

```
String a[] = new String[]{"1","2","3"};
```

Ahora este.

```
String a[] = "Hola Mundo !".split(" ");
```

El siguiente código lo probé en ideone, [aquí](https://ideone.com/rGrvgo), y funciona bien, me devuelve, `"El índice no existe"`. Quizás necesites crear tu propia clase *Cadena*, con un método *mostrar*, que implemente esa función.

```
String a[] = "Hola Mundo !".split(" ");
int longitud = a.length;
int b = 3;
if (b >=  longitud)
{
    System.out.println("El indice no existe");
}
else
{
    System.out.println(a[b]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema al separar por espacios es el mismo que en el primer ejemplo y la solución es la misma

```
String a[] = "Hola Mundo !".split(" ");
if ( a.length>=4 )
  System.out.println(a[3]);
else
  System.out.println( "No hay al menos 4 palabras");
```

`"Hola Mundo !"` contiene dos subcadenas `" "` y al aplicarle `.split(" ")` devuelve un array con tres elementos que son :

- a[0] = "Hola"
- a[1] = "Mundo"
- a[2] = "!"

Por tanto intentar acceder a `a[3]` provoca una excecpción de acceso a array fuera de límites y la solución es comprobar el tamaño del array antes de acceder.